# How to cache whole next.js's HTML page in Redis?

Tags: redis, next.js, node-redis

I'm new to next.js. I'm trying to cache the whole HTML page in next.js. So, that I can reduce the response time in the next call for that page.

I tried by creating a custom server and then save the response that came from rendertoHTML()/render(). But it didn't return any response.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is not for caching whole HTML pages or any other complex object types for that matter. It's key–value database. In Redis you should keep your object simple.

For your case it's best to use stale-while-revalidate ([SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/)) cache-control headers in combination with getServerSideProps for server-rendering in NextJS.
See here for [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/ssr-caching).

Comment: But html string can be stored in redis against keys ( representative of a unique page ) still right? How could we leverage that to store html for pages itself in redis so that Next.js do not spend request runtime for each page creating the html string.

Comment: read this [doc](https://makerkit.dev/blog/tutorials/nextjs-redis), maybe it helps.